# Text in table is going outside of document. Automatic line-breaking needed

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I'm facing some issues with my two-column table. The second column which contains a description is causing problems. I want the second column to automatically begin a new line whenever it is exceeding the text width of the document.

Also, I have a problem regarding placement of titles within the table.  Currently, as you can see, text in the second column is being moved over by the "Case 1" title from column one. Ideally, the first column should not affect the second in this manner.

This is my code:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm},bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}      

\usepackage{amsmath}                      
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tabularx}                     
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}   

\begin{document}
        \begin{table}[H] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llp{4cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Definition}   \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{General variables} \\
    $K$ & Fixed amount of money need to start production \\
    $s$ & Baseline quality of the good (normalized to 1) \\
    $n$ & Number of people \\
    $\pi_1, \pi_2, \Pi$ & Profits of the entrepreneur in the first period ($\pi_1$), in the second period ($\pi_2$) and total profits $\Pi = \pi_1 + \pi_1$) \\
    $P_r$ & $P_r$ is the regular price \\
    \textbf{Case 1: This is a very long title2} \\
    $\alpha$ & $\alpha$ is specific for Case 1 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \floatfoot{ \textit{Note}: This table....
                \textit{Source}: Source to be inserted}
    \caption{Definition of variables}
    \label{table_alm}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is the current output:

[image]

Comment: fully compilable MWE please.

Comment: why have you specified four columns?

Comment: @Naphaneal Done

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, reused the code from a previous table in my document.

Comment: It just complicates your code (and possible answers) l and r are single line, you presumably want to make one column be a `p` column and (because you made Variable span both columns) you get spurious column padding either side of the empty `r` columns.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, so change the column to the right to "p"?

Comment: p{4cm} or whatever width you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37916/discussion-between-saud-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: change \begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}. Remove one l  and compile. You will get the desired result

Comment: @murugan, I've tried with \begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}. But I don't get the (fully) desired result. The only thing that is missing is that I don't want the text in the right column to be sensitive to the titles in the first column (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
     \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
  \usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm},bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}      

  \usepackage{amsmath}                      
  \usepackage{mathtools} 
  \usepackage{tabularx}                     
  \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}   

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lp{6cm}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{\hskip-1.2in Definition}   \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{General variables} \\
        $K$ & \hskip-1.2in Fixed amount of money need to start production \\
        $s$ & \hskip-1.2in Baseline quality of the good (normalized to 1) \\
        $n$ & \hskip-1.2in Number of people \\
        $\pi_1, \pi_2, \Pi$ & \hskip-1.2in%
 \vtop{\hsize=3.5in Profits of the entrepreneur in the first period ($\pi_1$),%
 in the second period ($\pi_2$) and total profits $\Pi = \pi_1 + \pi_1$)} \\
        $P_r$ & \hskip-1.2in $P_r$ is the regular price%
   \vspace{.05in}\\
         \textbf{Case 1: This is a very long title2} \\
        $\alpha$ & \hskip-1.2in $\alpha$ is specific for Case 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
     \vskip.1in\par
     {\textit{Note}: This table....
        \textit{Source}: Source to be inserted}
    \caption{Definition of variables}
    \label{table_alm}
\end{table}

  \end{document}
```

Which produces: [image]

Comment: @A Feldman, thank you for your input! I just need the "Definition" title to b left-centered. I tried with "\begin{tabular}{llp{7cm}}" and "\textbf{Variable} & {l}\textbf{Definition}", but it didn't work. Also tried using "\raggedleft" but it crashed in the tabular-environment.

Comment: @Saud I went ahead and moved "Definition" over.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Mission accomplished! :)

Comment: Good, glad that it works for you.